# How to find the number of Uppercase and lowercase letters in a text file using Scanner?

Tags: java

I am completely new to the Java world and I'm so lost right now. I am doing a project where I have to get an input file (input.txt) and cipher it down to everything known. This is the problem right here...

- Next, for each category as described below, your program should determine the value that appears most frequently within the input.
- Next display this number of appearances and also the most frequently appearing value in each category. If two or more values are tied for most appearances, then you may choose any one of these values to display.

These are the categories:

- Upper-case letter
- Lower-case letter
- Case-insensitive letter (for example, do not distinguish ‘b’ and ‘B’)
- Digit
- Symbol (any visible non-alphanumeric character)
- Invisible character (blank, tab=‘\t’, newline=‘\n’, or return=‘\r’; display these characters by name)
- Word (maximal consecutive sequence of letters)
- Case-insensitive word
- Token (maximal consecutive sequence of visible characterssuch as letters, digits, and/or symbols)
- Case-insensitive token

I just need to know how to get Upper and lower case letters right now. If someone can help with that, I can have a good base to start with.

and here is my text file(input.txt) if you need it to reference by:

```
roll tide roll!
Roll Tide Roll!
ROLL TIDE ROLL!
ROll tIDE ROll!
 roll  tide  roll! 
 Roll  Tide  Roll! 
 ROLL  TIDE  ROLL! 
  roll   tide   roll!   
    Roll  Tide   Roll   !
```

All the help from an experienced Java programmer would be greatly appreciated! Thank you.

Comment: Any `Homework` tag is available here?

Comment: @VimalBera The `homework` tag was depreciated a while ago...

Answer (score 2):

Start by taking a read through the [Scanning](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/essential/io/scanning.html) tutorial.

Once you have the basics, you can use something along the lines of ...

```
String text = scanner.nextLine();
```

To retrieve the next line from the file.

From there you can use [`String#toCharArray`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toCharArray%28%29) to get an array of characters that represent the `String`.

You will need to loop through this array and use [`Character.isUpperCase`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Character.html#isUpperCase%28char%29) to determine the case of the given character.

You'll also need to be able to use a [`for-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/for.html) and [`while-loop`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/while.html) to achieve this, but the tutorials have some basic examples which should get you moving...

Answer (score 0):

You have to first import package of scanner class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;
```

After that you have to make an object of scanner class. After creating object any variable and then call it through the `nextLine method`. And after that using for loop or while loop you can put statements in it.

There have to convert the whole string into characters by giveing `toCharArray` and each character will check for Uppercase and lowercase.

Mention your code here so i can help you more clearly.